# How to create game sound for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, audio

How to make some good quality sounds for iPhone game applications so that the applications will become some more attractive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check Soundsnap for gettings Sounds. Also you can use Audacity for making sounds on your own

- http://www.soundsnap.com/
- http://audacity.sourceforge.net/