# create sounds for iphone game

Tags: iphone, audio

I'm searching for a possibility or something wherewith I can create sounds for e.g. an iphone game. Are there any applications?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ... what types of sounds? what formats? are these going to be recorded sounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in this:

> You could check Soundsnap for gettings Sounds. Also you can use Audacity for making sounds on your own
>
> http://www.soundsnap.com/
>
> http://audacity.sourceforge.net/

SO Resource: [how to get game sound or how to create good sound for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027860/how-to-get-game-sound-or-how-to-create-good-sound-for-iphone/3028432#3028432)